# How to decrease the code size when there is some same code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sorry about I don't know how to explain this...for example, here is my code:

```
def get_hash(choice):
    if choice == 1:
        sha1 = hashlib.sha1()                                                               
        sha1.update('a test for sha1'.encode('utf-8'))                                  
        print(sha1.hexdigest())                                                          

    elif choice == 2:                                                                          
        sha256 = hashlib.sha256()                                                        
        sha256.update('a test for sha256'.encode('utf-8'))                              
        print(sha256.hexdigest())  

get_hash(int(input('Enter your choice between one and two: '))
```

Look, choice 1 and choice 2 only 'sha1' and 'sha256' are difference.

So I want to know, how to decrease the code size? Can I do some thing like `'sha{0} = hashlib.sha{0}'.format('256')`?

Comment: You should not use `hash` as the name of your own function (or variable), as that shadows the built-in `hash` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite your hash function to take the hasher as an argument.

```
def hash_test(hasher):                                                             
    hasher.update('a hash test'.encode('utf-8'))                                  
    print(hasher.hexdigest())     

hashes = {'sha256': hashlib.sha256(), 'sha1': hashlib.sha1()}

hash_type = input('Do you want to try sha1, or sha256?')
hasher = hashes[hash_type]
hash_test(hasher)
```

There's no (sane) way to create/use dynamic variables names, especially if you're trying to create objects from a library.

Comment: @KevinGuan Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

In python, [everything is an object](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html)!

```
hashlib_mapping = {
    1: "sha1",
    2: "sha256",
    ... }

def hash(choice):
    hasher = getattr(hashlib, hashlib_mapping[choice])()
               ^1^                ^2^                 ^3^
```

That means, you can map values with method names. Then use `getattr` (1) to get related method (2) of th hashlib class and call it(3). You can even use sha method numbers as below

```
# Pass sha method number to define the relatd sha method. 
hasher = getattr(hashlib, "sha{num}".format(num=choice))()

hash(1)  # will use sha1
hash(224)  # will use sha224
hash(384)  # will use sha384
```

Comment: Hum, I understand. This is a good proposal. I'll refer this :)

Comment: @KevinGuan: You can do some very powerful things with `getattr`. But remember, with great power comes great responsibility. And the potential for great confusion. :)

Comment: @FallenAngel Thanks. Let me learn more about the `getattr` :)

Comment: @PM2Ring yes it is powerful, but it is not that much dangerous (at least not as much as `eval` or `exec`). I prefer to check received parameter (`choice` in this example) whether it is an expected parameter or not etc. But question is asking for shorter script and that answer works as expected. Beyond that, a programmer must know/learn pros and cons (and caveats) of a method that he will use and this is totally a different subject.

Comment: @FallenAngel: Sure, `getattr` is **much** safer than `exec` / `eval`, and it is an indispensable tool, but I prefer to use safer, simpler tools when they can do the job at hand. That way, when you make a mistake the potential for havoc is smaller, and its easier to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, but it is all up to the programmer I guess. Using commends to explain expected input and checking if received parameter is valid will keep you safe. But on the other hand, using `getattr` for a such simple task may look not-logical, but that is a way to go and it makes your code simper (and make you need to use much less check statements) when there are too many options for executing very similar code blocks.

Comment: Hey, I've just seen the document of `getattr`. However it's so good! and @FallenAngel , use `getattr` and a *dictionary* is a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and keeping one argument in your function:

```
def hash(choice):
    map_dico = { 1: [ 'sha1', hashlib.sha1()] ,
                 2: [ 'sha256', hashlib.sha256() ]}                                                                 
    map_dico[choice][1].update('a test for {}'.format(map_dico[choice][0]).encode('utf-8'))                                  
    print(map_dico[choice][1].hexdigest())   

hash(int(input('Enter your choice between one and two: ')) )
```

Comment: well, at  `2: [sha1, hashlib.sha256()}`, I got a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: still not working, and however I like @Morgan 's answer better.

Comment: well, let me try again.

Comment: this error: `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`. at `map_dico[choice][1].update('a test for '+map_dico[choice][0]+''.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: @KevinGuan Ok, my bad, you're on python 3, corrected (See Edit)

Comment: Now it's working. I'll refer this and @Morgan Thrapp 's code. Thank you :)

Comment: FWIW, the map_dico dictionary _could be replaced by a tuple of tuples (or a tuple of lists, etc): `(None, ('sha1', hashlib.sha1()), ('sha256', hashlib.sha256()))`